# Set up new Wordpress domain using unclear files

Tags: plugins, themes, html, static-website

I am assisting a development agency on a trial basis, and I was tasked with setting up a new Wordpress site using files obtained from a different agency.

After setting up the installation and transferring across the files, I am having issues.

According to the agency who supplied the files, the following two sites are direct implementations of these files: [Handout](https://handout.co.za/) and [SoccerShop](http://competitions.soccershop.mobi/).

The above sites appear to be static, and as I was not given any database backups even after asking if these files are correct, I am assuming they are static sites that do not use any posts/pages from a database.

Image of file structure:

[image: File Structure]

The default theme is a custom theme that closely resembles the above 2 webpages in it's thumbnail, but when using it I get a simple Wordpress blog that is using posts/pages from the database.

What I am most confused about is the '_handout' folder in the above file structure. Inside, there are 3 .html files, and using only those 3 files along with the 'css' and 'js' folders accompanying them, I get the below page, which closely resembles the 2 example pages, but is completely static and not using the Wordpress platform at all.

[image]

Anybody have any thoughts on this? I'm unsure if my knowledge of Wordpress is too limited to wrap my head around this, or if this is some mix of Wordpress/static that requires special knowledge to be able to implement.

Comment: There is no way to reproduce the site from just the files without data loss, the content is stored in the database. The Handout site is definitely not static. As for the `demo` and `handout` folders, who knows, I don't believe it's possible for anybody to tell without reading the code in full. But more importantly, this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, what is your question? Is it a question or a discussion? Is the site actually hosted on wordpress.com platform?

Comment: Have you checked everywhere for the DB backup? The site backups we get from our designers usually have the DB backup in the wp-content folder. Or what's godaddy.zip? That looks big enough to be a DB backup too (if not too big).